# Akka - How can an actor get a reference to a web service

Tags: java, akka, actor

I have the following basic setup:

```
public static void main(...) {
  final MyWebServiceClient client = new MyWebServiceClient(...,....,....);
  ...
  final ActorRef master = system.actorOf(Props.create(Level1Actor.class), "level1");
  master.tell(new Level1Message()...);
}
```

`Level1Actor.onRecieve()` creates several Level2Actors:

```
...
getContext().actorOf(Props.create(Level2Actor.class)).tell(new Level2Message(), getSelf());
...
```

and similarly Level2Actor.onReceive creates several Level3Actors

Here's my question:  In Level3Actor.onRecieve() I want to use the web service client I created in my main method, something like:

```
public void onReceive() {
...
EmailSummary summary = client.getEmailSummary(username, password, etc, etc);
//create and send a response to sender based on 'summary'
...
}
```

How do I achieve this?  Ideally I want to configure my web service at startup (urls etc) and  then access it several layers of Actor deep?

Is there a way in my main method to register some factory that is called whenever an actor is created?  like:

```
system.register(Level3Actor.class, myFactoryWithReferenceToWebService);
```

?  Or from a Spring point of view my web service would be a bean and just be autowired into the Level3Actor instances?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [Extension](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/extending-akka.html).  They are a nice way to provide "global" stuff to actors:

```
public class MyWebServiceExtension extends
  AbstractExtensionId<MyWebServiceExtension.MyWebServiceExt> {

  public static MyWebServiceExtension MyWebServiceExtProvider = 
    new MyWebServiceExtension();

  public MyWebServiceExt createExtension(ExtendedActorSystem system) {
    return new MyWebServiceExt();
  }

  public static class MyWebServiceExt implements Extension {
    private final MyWebServiceClient client = new MyWebServiceClient();

    public MyWebServiceClient getClient() { return client; }
  }
}
```

Then in your actor:

```
import static com.foo.MyWebServiceExtension.MyWebServiceExtProvider;

public class MyUntypedActor extends UntypedActor {
  final MyWebServiceClient client =
    MyWebServiceExtProvider.get(getContext().system()).getClient();
```

Or if you are using Spring you can use the [IndirectActorProducer](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/akka/actor/IndirectActorProducer.html) and let Spring DI your dependencies into your actors.  See [this project](https://github.com/typesafehub/activator-akka-java-spring) for an example.

Comment: thanks for this, it's exactly what I was after, I'll give the spring option a go

Comment: Inner implementation class is very useful. Even the doc says to use two classes as for interface and the actual implementation. But as shown here having a single class makes code more clean

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions are:

1. Define the webservice ref as a property of your message classes (`Level1Message`, `Level2Message`, etc..) and propagate it down the chain via message passing.
2. Define your actors that need the webservice as having a constructor that accepts the webservice as an arg.  Then, when creating those actors, use the `Props.create` that accepts constructor args like so:

   ```
   getContext().actorOf(Props.create(Level2Actor.class, client))
   ```